# Getting error when changing Ansible password

Tags: ansible, change-password

I am building an ansible playbook to change multiple passwords on our network. And it works! It changes all of the passwords like it is supposed to. However, the last password it changes is the ansible password, which then throws an error because it tries to do the success check using the old Ansible password. Is there a way to tell Ansible to use a different password after changing the password?  Below is the entire playbook.

```yaml
---
# Update local administrator on all Windows systems
- hosts: windows
  gather_facts: yes
  ignore_errors: no
  tasks:
   - name: Set Windows Administrator password
     ansible.windows.win_user:
      name: administrator
      update_password: always
      password: "{{ new_win_admin_pass }}"    
   - name: Set ansible password.
     ansible.windows.win_user:
      name: ansible
      update_password: always
      password: "{{ new_ansible_pass }}"

# Update all Linux accounts.
# This must always run last, once ansible password is changed, no further changes can occur.
- hosts: rhel
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  ignore_errors: no
  tasks:
    - name: Set Workstation admin password.
      hosts: rhel_workstations
      ansible.builtin.user:
        name: admin
        update_password: always
        password: "{{ new_admin_pass | password_hash ('sha512')}}"
    - name: Set Linux root password.
      ansible.builtin.user:
        name: root
        update_password: always
        password: "{{ new_root_pass | password_hash ('sha512')}}"
    - name: Set ansible password.
      ansible.builtin.user:
        name: ansible
        update_password: always
        password: "{{ new_ansible_pw_var | password_hash ('sha512')}}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try to do this with an [async task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html) and check back on the result with the new password:

```yaml
- hosts: rhel
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Set ansible password.
      ansible.builtin.user:
        name: ansible
        update_password: always
        password: "{{ new_ansible_pw_var | password_hash ('sha512')}}"
     async: 15
     poll: 0
     register: change_ansible_password

   - name: Check ansible password change was successful
     vars:
       ansible_password: "{{ new_ansible_pw_var }}"
     async_status:
       jid: "{{ change_ansible_password.ansible_job_id }}"
     register: job_result
     until: job_result.finished
     retries: 15
     delay: 1

   - name: polite guests always clean after themselves when necessary (see doc)
     vars:
       ansible_password: "{{ new_ansible_pw_var }}"
     async_status:
       jid: "{{ change_ansible_password.ansible_job_id }}"
       mode: cleanup
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I'm brand new to Ansible, didn't even know async tasks were a thing.